# Importing CSV date column to SQL changes date

Tags: csv, date, import

I'm experiencing an issue where when I import using SQL import, or ETL job, a CSV Excel type file into SQL that the dates are being converted or altered to something else.

I'm trying to ID a pattern but for example here are two date samples. before and after:

```
Before         After
=======        =======
30/01/2015     20/01/1930
11/09/2015     20/09/2011
```

Seems like the day number is being used to replace the year portion, and in first case century reverts to 19, and the original century portion is, in some cases, overwriting the day, if that makes sense?

I can't see why it would do this, none of the other files I had done this, and they were all Excel CSV files. They were transferred the same way to the same data mart from the same file location.

It's scary to think one file can suddenly do this with no error being raised, and just lucky it was spotted in the end reports.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the SQL dialect you are using. For example, Mysql only accepts dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.
The Date format in excel is 06/09/2015.

To make sure everything is okay, just explicitly set the Date format in Excel. 
 In order to change the date format in excel: right click on the top cell. Choose format cells from the drop down list. change the local to something like 'Afrikans'. Choose the format that looks like 2001-03-14. Use the top cell to fill down. Then save the document.